# How to change content of unity text?

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine

I create an application on unity3d. I use `Unity 5.0.2f1 (64-bit)`. I create a new project and add an empty gameobject. I click gameobject and add a `gui text` from inspector. My `gui text` is below :

[image]

I want to change the contenf of this text at each frame. I use below code but it doesn't change it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

private int count = 0;
public GUIText guiText;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    guiText.text = "Counter";
}
}
```

What should I do? I see `asddffbhfbehfbhj` every time.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you sure that the guiText is set in the inspector?

Comment: no I don't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach this script to your gameobject(the same game object that guitext is attached to)then assign the guitext component of your game object to your script via inspector(drag you guitext component and drop it in guitext variable that you see within your script component in inspector)